# SQL Query to Find All distinct Duplicates across 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

```
      Sale ID          Group ID
JED93B53QEJYST4102  01A42QEJAXT17A7
JED93B53QEJYST4102  01A42QEJAXT17A7
JED93B53QEJYST4102  01A42QEJAXT17A7
JED93B53QEJYST4102  01A42QEJAXT17A7
JED8754AQEJEHT4119  01C49QEJPJT133E
JED8754AQEJEHT4119  01C49QEJPJT133E
JED8754AQEJEHT4119  01C49QEJPJT133E
JEDA67C1QEJEQR4A4A  03D80QEJRSR1BC5
JEDA67C1QEJEQR4A4A  03D80QEJRSR1BC5
JED46D04QEJXOR468B  040E5QEJGQR174D
JED658D9QEJIOS4F38  053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED658D9QEJIOS4F38  053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED99C53QEJNMR4973  053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED658D9QEJIOS4F38  053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED658D9QEJIOS4F38  053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED457D4QEJFGR468F  0B829QEJHJR18F5
JED457D4QEJFGR468F  0B829QEJHJR18F5
JEDA98F8QEJCZQ4F6A  0B829QEJHJR18F5
```

I am stuck in a dilemma wherein I am trying to write a SQL Query that will give me only those records which has duplicate group IDs but with unique Sale IDs. My Expected Output is similar to below. Is there anyway to achieve this?

```
JED99C53QEJNMR4973  053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED658D9QEJIOS4F38  053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED457D4QEJFGR468F  0B829QEJHJR18F5
JEDA98F8QEJCZQ4F6A  0B829QEJHJR18F5
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Using Group By I can achieve till this:

```
Sale ID                       Group ID
JED93B53QEJYST4102         01A42QEJAXT17A7
JED8754AQEJEHT4119         01C49QEJPJT133E
JEDA67C1QEJEQR4A4A         03D80QEJRSR1BC5
JED46D04QEJXOR468B         040E5QEJGQR174D
JED658D9QEJIOS4F38         053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED99C53QEJNMR4973         053BDQEJNSS11D4
JED457D4QEJFGR468F         0B829QEJHJR18F5
JEDA98F8QEJCZQ4F6A         0B829QEJHJR18F5
```

EDIT FINAL: Thanks for all the responses and the finally was able to sort this out the way I wanted it. I managed to learn something new. Apologies if my question was not clear. I required it precisely that way as the table has more than a 100,000 records and I need to audit those with different SaleID for a single GroupID. The below query by Giorgos Betsos worked

```
    SELECT t1.[Sale ID], t1.[Group ID]
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT [Group ID]       
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY [Group ID]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT [Sale ID]) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.[Group ID] = t2.[Group ID]
Group By t1.[Group ID], t1.[Sale ID]
```

Comment: Your suggested output disagrees with what you described you want.

Comment: I am modifying the first post as I am unable to use the code option here

Comment: Two of the answers given below should solve your problem.

Comment: It seems a simple Join was needed and that is what all 3 of the answers pointed to. Thank you all for assisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the required `GROUP ID` values can be obtained by the following query:

```
SELECT [Group ID]       
FROM mytable
GROUP BY [Group ID]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT [Sale ID]) > 1
```

You can use the above query as a derived to table to join back to the original table so as to get the `Sale ID` value as well:

```
SELECT t1.[Sale ID], t1.[Group ID]
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT [Group ID]       
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY [Group ID]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT [Sale ID]) > 1
) AS t2 ON t1.[Group ID] = t2.[Group ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

> write a SQL Query that will give me only those records which has duplicate group IDs but with unique Sale IDs

Here is how to do this verbatim:

```
SELECT t1.[Sale ID],
       t1.[Group ID]
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Group ID]
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY [Group ID]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND                         -- duplicate group IDs
           COUNT(DISTINCT [Sale ID]) = COUNT(*)     -- but all sale IDs unique
) t2
    ON t1.[Group ID] = t2.[Group ID]
```

However, your desired output seemed to suggest something more simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Sale ID], [Group ID]
FROM yourTable
```

or

```
SELECT [Sale ID], [Group ID]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY [Sale ID], [Group ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    DECLARE @Table TABLE (
        [Sale ID] VARCHAR(100)
        ,[Group ID] VARCHAR(100)
        )
     insert into @Table values 
    ('JED93B53QEJYST4102','01A42QEJAXT17A7')
    ,('JED93B53QEJYST4102','01A42QEJAXT17A7')
    ,('JED93B53QEJYST4102','01A42QEJAXT17A7')
    ,('JED93B53QEJYST4102','01A42QEJAXT17A7')
    ,('JED8754AQEJEHT4119','01C49QEJPJT133E')
    ,('JED8754AQEJEHT4119','01C49QEJPJT133E')
    ,('JED8754AQEJEHT4119','01C49QEJPJT133E')
    ,('JEDA67C1QEJEQR4A4A','03D80QEJRSR1BC5')
    ,('JEDA67C1QEJEQR4A4A','03D80QEJRSR1BC5')
    ,('JED46D04QEJXOR468B','040E5QEJGQR174D')
    ,('JED658D9QEJIOS4F38','053BDQEJNSS11D4')
    ,('JED658D9QEJIOS4F38','053BDQEJNSS11D4')
    ,('JED99C53QEJNMR4973','053BDQEJNSS11D4')
    ,('JED658D9QEJIOS4F38','053BDQEJNSS11D4')
    ,('JED658D9QEJIOS4F38','053BDQEJNSS11D4')
    ,('JED457D4QEJFGR468F','0B829QEJHJR18F5')
    ,('JED457D4QEJFGR468F','0B829QEJHJR18F5')
    ,('JEDA98F8QEJCZQ4F6A','0B829QEJHJR18F5')

SELECT DISTINCT t1.[Sale ID]
    ,t1.[Group ID]
FROM @Table AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT [Group ID]
    FROM @Table
    GROUP BY [Group ID]
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Sale ID]) > 1
    ) AS t2 ON t1.[Group ID] = t2.[Group ID]
```